# How to find complex roots in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, equation

I have a equation but how I will find roots of function?

This is my equation;

```
eqn =  (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-(yansima^2*T^2)))
```

s11, s22, s21, s12 are complex number.

Other parameters;

```
y = i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er)))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = ((y0/m0)-(y/m))/((y0/m0)+(y/m));
T = exp(-y*l);
```

Er is unknown. It is symbol. Like x. I know other parameters and they are complex (w, Mr, isik_hizi, etc.)
I want to find function (eqn) roots. How can I do it in MATLAB?

This is my main program;

```
%%NRW Yöntemi%%%
clc
clear all
% yansima_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
yansima_genlik= .856;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(yansima_genlik) ' dir. '])
%yansima_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
yansima_faz= 163.2;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(yansima_faz) ' dir. '])

s11 = yansima_genlik*cosd(yansima_faz)+i*yansima_genlik*sind(yansima_faz);
s22 = s11;

%gecis_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
gecis_genlik= .609;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(gecis_genlik) ' dir. '])
%gecis_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
gecis_faz= -140.5;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(gecis_faz) ' dir. '])

s21 = gecis_genlik*cosd(gecis_faz)+i*gecis_genlik*sind(gecis_faz);
s12 = s21;
f= 8*10^9;

l=0.4; %örnek uzunluğu

fc=5.26*10^9; %kesim frekansı

lamda0 = 3.75;
lamdac = 5.703;

x = (s11^2-s21^2+1)/(2*s11)

yansima1 = x + sqrt(x^2-1)
yansima2 = x - sqrt(x^2-1)

iletim = (s11+s21-yansima1)/(1-(s11+s21)*yansima1)

a = log(1/iletim) 

%b = -((1/(2*pi*l))*a)^2);

b = -(((1/(2*pi*l))*a)^2)

v = sqrt(1/b)

p = 1/v

Mr= (1+yansima1)/(v*(1-yansima1)*sqrt((1/lamda0)^2-(1/lamdac)^2))
%Mr=1;
Er= (lamda0^2/Mr)*(((1/lamdac)^2)+b);
Er_1= real(Er)
Er_2=imag(Er)




%%%NIST Iterative Yöntemi
e0 = 8.85*10^-12;
m0 = 4*pi*10^-7;
b=3;
l1 = 1;
l2 =1;
la = l1+l2+l;

w= 2*pi*f;
isik_hizi = 1/sqrt(e0*m0);
Mr = 1;
m=m0*Mr;

y = i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = ((y0/m0)-(y/m))/((y0/m0)+(y/m));
T = exp(-y*l);
syms Er
eqn =  (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-(yansima^2*T^2)))
```

Comment: You say that you want find roots of `eqn`, but do you mean square roots (or any other roots `^(1/n)` ) or roots like `fnc(x) = 0` (but in this case what is your `x`) ?

Comment: Yes I want to find roots of eqn. My function is eqn. X is Er. So Er is unknown.
Example:
`f(x) = x^2 + 3*x + 2
Roots : -2, -1`

My function `F(Er) = (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-(yansima^2*T^2)))`

Comment: I think there is something i don't understand but in your function you have `F(Er) = (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-‌​(yansima^2*T^2)))` but `(s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-‌​(yansima^2*T^2)))` doesn't depend of Er. It's like you have `for all x, f(x) = 4`

Comment: No, function depends on Er. Because my function is; `eqn =  (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-(yansima^2*T^2)))`
And y value has Er. `y = i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er)))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));`

Comment: I don't think matlab interpret this like a function because you defined `Er` as a constant `Er= (lamda0^2/Mr)*(((1/lamdac)^2)+b);`. So i think `eqn` is a constant and not a function. You use `syms` but i'm not enough familiar with this command but you can use `@` to create function

Comment: I used `syms Er` at the bottom. But t I don't know the continuation. So I asked this answer.

Comment: I don't use `syms` at all but, I think you must write `syms Er`before you first use it in `y = i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));` and after that you can use `solve` defined in https://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defined a function using `@` by writing:

```
y = @(Er) i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
```

In this case, y is a function and you can use `y(5)` to evaluate it value. You do the same for `yansima`and `eqn`.

```
yansima = @(Er) ((y0/m0)-(y(Er)/m))/((y0/m0)+(y(Er)/m));
eqn = @(Er) (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima(Er)^2))/(1-(yansima(Er)^2*T^2)))
```

And then you can solve your equation using `fsolve`.

**EDIT**

```
clc
clear all
% yansima_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
yansima_genlik= .856;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(yansima_genlik) ' dir. '])
%yansima_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
yansima_faz= 163.2;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(yansima_faz) ' dir. '])


s11 = yansima_genlik*cosd(yansima_faz)+i*yansima_genlik*sind(yansima_faz);
s22 = s11;

%gecis_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
gecis_genlik= .609;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(gecis_genlik) ' dir. '])
%gecis_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
gecis_faz= -140.5;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(gecis_faz) ' dir. '])

s21 = gecis_genlik*cosd(gecis_faz)+i*gecis_genlik*sind(gecis_faz);
s12 = s21;
f= 8*10^9;

l=0.4; %örnek uzunluğu

fc=5.26*10^9; %kesim frekansı

lamda0 = 3.75;
lamdac = 5.703;

x = (s11^2-s21^2+1)/(2*s11)

yansima1 = x + sqrt(x^2-1)
yansima2 = x - sqrt(x^2-1)

iletim = (s11+s21-yansima1)/(1-(s11+s21)*yansima1)

a = log(1/iletim) 

%b = -((1/(2*pi*l))*a)^2);

b = -(((1/(2*pi*l))*a)^2)

v = sqrt(1/b)

p = 1/v

Mr= (1+yansima1)/(v*(1-yansima1)*sqrt((1/lamda0)^2-(1/lamdac)^2))
%Mr=1;
Er= (lamda0^2/Mr)*(((1/lamdac)^2)+b);
Er_1= real(Er)
Er_2=imag(Er)




%%%NIST Iterative Yöntemi
e0 = 8.85*10^-12;
m0 = 4*pi*10^-7;
b=3;
l1 = 1;
l2 =1;
la = l1+l2+l;

w= 2*pi*f;
isik_hizi = 1/sqrt(e0*m0);
Mr = 1;
m=m0*Mr;

y = @(Er) i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = @(Er) ((y0/m0)-(y(Er)/m))/((y0/m0)+(y(Er)/m));
T = @(Er) exp(-y(Er)*l);
eqn = @(Er) (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T(Er)^2)-(yansima(Er)^2))/(1-(yansima(Er)^2*T(Er)^2)));

options = optimset(optimset('fsolve'), 'TolFun', 1.0e-12, 'TolX',1.0e-12);
sol = fsolve(eqn, 0, options);
```

When using `optimset`, you can change the précision of the solution, and the parameter `0` in fsolve is the `x0` for the solution.

Comment: Can you add main program? I don't know mean @ or fsolve. And I want to only roots of eqn. Not yansima. And T has y value. So T has Er.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand solve. Where is the roots? I want to roots.

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't help you more if you want using `solve`, but edit your question and ask clearly for a solution using solve but if you want more help  using `fsolve` I can help you.

Comment: I will ask new question and it will be clearly. I hope you can help me. But I have 6 reputation. I need 10 reputation. When I have 10 reputation, I will ask question.

Comment: Can you look my new question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453185/how-can-i-write-in-matlab) @Théo P.