# How can I write in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, iteration

I solved NRW(Nicholson-Ross-Weir Conversion Method) conversion method and I found epsilonr(Er).

**NRW Conversion Method**

```
clc
clear all
% yansima_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
yansima_genlik= .856;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(yansima_genlik) ' dir. '])
%yansima_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
yansima_faz= 163.2;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(yansima_faz) ' dir. '])


s11 = yansima_genlik*cosd(yansima_faz)+i*yansima_genlik*sind(yansima_faz);
s22 = s11;

%gecis_genlik= input('Genliği giriniz =')
gecis_genlik= .609;
%disp(['Genlik: ' num2str(gecis_genlik) ' dir. '])
%gecis_faz= input('Fazı giriniz =')
gecis_faz= -140.5;
%disp(['Faz açısı: ' num2str(gecis_faz) ' dir. '])

s21 = gecis_genlik*cosd(gecis_faz)+i*gecis_genlik*sind(gecis_faz);
s12 = s21;
f= 8*10^9;

l=0.4; %örnek uzunluğu

fc=5.26*10^9; %kesim frekansı

lamda0 = 3.75;
lamdac = 5.703;

x = (s11^2-s21^2+1)/(2*s11)

yansima1 = x + sqrt(x^2-1)
yansima2 = x - sqrt(x^2-1)

iletim = (s11+s21-yansima1)/(1-(s11+s21)*yansima1)

a = log(1/iletim) 

b = -(((1/(2*pi*l))*a)^2)

v = sqrt(1/b)

p = 1/v

Mr= (1+yansima1)/(v*(1-yansima1)*sqrt((1/lamda0)^2-(1/lamdac)^2))
%Mr=1;
Er= (lamda0^2/Mr)*(((1/lamdac)^2)+b);
Er_1= real(Er)
Er_2=imag(Er)
```

[image: NIST Iterative Method]
But my problem this pictures. I want to write "NIST Iterative Conversion Method" in MATLAB.
I wrote part of the command. But I couldn't write more. Because I don't understand the algorithm.

**NIST Iterative Method** (Some Part)

```
%%%NIST Iterative Yöntemi
e0 = 8.85*10^-12;
m0 = 4*pi*10^-7;
b=3;
l1 = 1;
l2 =1;
la = l1+l2+l;

w= 2*pi*f;
isik_hizi = 1/sqrt(e0*m0);
Mr = 1;
m=m0*Mr;

y = i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er_1+i*Er_2))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = ((y0/m0)-(y/m))/((y0/m0)+(y/m));
T = exp(-y*l);
fx =  (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T^2)-(yansima^2))/(1-(yansima^2*T^2)))
```

Please help me. I want to write in MATLAB. But I don't know command.

Comment: I shortly look into the *NIST Iterative Method* with https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/00aps_undefined/RAC-0607-0019_1_5E.pdf (p.24) but I really don't know how to calculate the Jacobian matrix. If you know how to do this, try to implement implement their alogrithm.

Comment: I have `F(Er)` function. It is fx in MATLAB. I need `f1(e',e'') and f2(e',e'')`. But how I will find roots of function? Because I need two roots. `Er1` and `Er2`. If I find roots, I will put in Jacobian matrix. `e' = real part of Er , e'' = imaginer part of Er. ` Jacobian matrix will be calculated as normal matrix. Just we will add `h` to the real and imaginary parts. So we will do the equation there and continue like a normal matrix.

Comment: Ok, if you need only 2 roots try using *fsolve*, like I told you yesterday. To have 2 roots you need, in the *fsolve* parameters to put 2 differently `x0`.
`[Er1, er2] = fsolve(eqn, [x01; x02], option)`. Look at the explenation i gave you yesterday. But you can't be certain that with `x01`and  `x02`.

Comment: Can you do it for me? Because I never use _fsolve_. I don't know what that means. You told me yesterday but I don't understand. Because I didn't show two roots. I found first `Er` in _NRW method, if you will use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want find two roots you could use *fslove* as below:

```
y = @(Er) i*sqrt((((w^2*Mr*(Er))/isik_hizi^2)-(2*pi/lamdac)^2));
y0 = i* sqrt((w/isik_hizi)^2-(2*pi/lamdac)^2);
yansima = @(Er) ((y0/m0)-(y(Er)/m))/((y0/m0)+(y(Er)/m));
T = @(Er) exp(-y(Er)*l);
fx = @(Er) (s11*s22-s21*s12-(exp(-2*y0)*(la-l))*((T(Er)^2)-(yansima(Er)^2))/(1-(yansima(Er)^2*T(Er)^2)))

options = optimset(optimset('fsolve'), 'TolFun', 1.0e-12, 'TolX',1.0e-12);
Er1 = fsolve(fx, x01, options);
Er2 = fsolve(fx, x02, options);
```

But like i don't know the NIST method I can't help you finding `x01` and `x02` but in *fsolve* will find the closest solution to `x01` (or `x02)` when `fx(Er1) ~= 0` where `Er1` is the closest solution to `x01`. If you want a solution close to your `Er` find in your first part, you can use `x01 = real(Er)`.

Comment: Yes, this is well. My purpose is to find the value close to the first `Er` by doing the iteration. So function (fx) will close to zero. So I must use `Newton-Raphson Method and Jacobian Matrix`. My first `Er = 5.72 + 7.21i`. When I use `x01 = 5.72` , Er1 becomes `5.67 - 0.02 i`. So 5.67 close to 5.72 but -0.02 not close to 7.21. I write `x01 = real(Er)`, what do I write x02? And then what will I do?

Comment: I don't know anything. I see this for the first time. Only I did NRW method. My teacher said to me; _Now, you can use NIST Iterative Method and you must write in MATLAB. So you can look at_ [NIST Iterative](https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/00aps_undefined/RAC-0607-0019_1_5E.pdf) (p.24,25,26)