# Newton-Raphson Iteration

Tags: matlab, iteration, complex-numbers

`x1` and `x2` are complex. Example : `x1 = x1reel+x1img*i` and `x2 = x2reel-x2img*i`. `x0` is first value and complex.

```
clc
clear all
% Define the given function
syms x1 x2

x=[x1,x2];

f(x)=[3*x1-cos(x1^2)-1/2;3*x2-cos(x2^2)-1/2];

% Define the stopping criteria based on Nither or relative errors

tol=10^-5; 
Niter=100;

df=jacobian(f,x);

x0=[complex;complex];

% Setting starting values

error=1; 
i=0; 

% Start the Newton-Raphson Iteration

while(abs(error)>tol)

f0=eval(f(x0(1),x0(2)));

df0=eval(df(x0(1),x0(2))); 

xnew=x0-df0\f0; % also tried lsqr(df0,f0),bicg(df0,f0)

error=norm(xnew-x0);

x0=xnew;

i=i+1

if i>=Niter

    fprintf('Iteration times spill over Niter\n');

    return;

end

end
```

I want to do Newton-Raphson Iteration. But I'm having difficulty because it is complex.

Comment: Any reason why you apply symbolic tools for a numerical method? Also your equations will give the same result for x1 and x2 as it is the same equation and the first and second component of your function is purely x1 or x2's (In other words, you can just solve one equation).

Comment: As Nicky says: its a numerical method, use only numerical maths. Also, what is the difficulty? Can you explain why it doesnt work? Note that the NR method behaves strangely in specific case and your code is not accounting for that!

Comment: I have only a equation. But I need to make a matrix. So I think I need 2 equations. This is not my equation. My equation is more complicated. I just wrote this equation for the example. My real equation is nonlinear. I have first x value and I need new x value. The new x value will bring the function closer to zero.

Comment: My real question there; [Iterative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453185/how-can-i-write-in-matlab)